# How to bind text box values to property of SelectedItem in ListBox

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, textbox, listbox

Sorry, XAML is new for me, so I apologize in advance if I sound like a noob.

I have items in the ListBox being dynamically added/deleted/etc, it is bound like so:

```
<ListBox Name="missionList" ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource missionLegTemplate}" SelectionChanged="missionList_SelectionChanged"/>
```

The items it is bound to are contained in a list that inherits from ObservableList. This list is my DataContext which is set at the start of the program:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = new MissionList();
    }
```

I have a series of text boxes which are intended to be used both to display current values of the object properties and save them as they are edited.

After reading around, I am getting the impression that I need to set the DataContext in the scope of the text boxes to the currently selected object in the ListBox, but I'm not sure how to access that object with XAML.

Does that make sense? Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I would probably move your MissionList into a ViewModel class, along with a new property for SelectedMission that can be bound to the ListBox's SelectedItem.

As an example (not necessarily working code):

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
}

public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Mission> MissionList { ... }
    public Mission SelectedMission { ... }
    .
    .
    .
}

<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MissionList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMission}" />
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=SelectedMission.SomeTextField, Mode=OneWay}" />
```